# Why getting Gson MalFormatException

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I have json string as below i want to convert to object

```
{"Init":{"MOP":[{"Id":"1","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXB","TerminalId":"P400Plus-275008565","IP":"10.0.0.0:900","Currency":"EUR"},{"Id":"2","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXF","TerminalId":"P400Plus-275008565","IP":"10.0.0.0:901","Currency":"EUR"}]}}
```

My json is valid , i tried on [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) also i created POJO class on [here](https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo)  but i'm getting `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException`

Here my code

```
    val receiveString = "{"Init":{"MOP":[{"Id":"1","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXB","TerminalId":"P400Plus-275008565","IP":"10.0.0.0:900","Currency":"EUR"},{"Id":"2","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXF","TerminalId":"P400Plus-275008565","IP":"10.0.0.0:901","Currency":"EUR"}]}}"
    val root = gson.fromJson(receiveString,TestClass.Root::class.java) //getting error here
```

Here my POJO class

```
class Root {
    @JsonProperty("Init")
    var init: Init? = null
}

class MOP {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    var id: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("Type")
    var type: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("ProtocolVersion")
    var protocolVersion: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("MopCode")
    var mopCode: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("TerminalId")
    var terminalId: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("IP")
    var ip: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("Currency")
    var currency: String? = null
}

class Init {
    @JsonProperty("MOP")
    var mop: List<MOP>? = null
}
```

What yu can suggest me?

Comment: Are you declaring `receiveString` without escaping every `"`?

Comment: @LorenzoZane yes json is valid

Answer (score 0):

doubleQuote (") in your string must be escaped like "

Comment: Can you make correction because looks to me normal..

Comment: replace all doubleQuote(") to (\")  

val receiveString = "{\"Init\":{\"MOP\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"0\",\"ProtocolVersion\":\"1.0\",\"MopCode\":\"*NEXB\",\"TerminalId\":\"P400Plus-275008565\",\"IP\":\"10.0.0.0:900\",\"Currency\":\"EUR\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Type\":\"0\",\"ProtocolVersion\":\"1.0\",\"MopCode\":\"*NEXF\",\"TerminalId\":\"P400Plus-275008565\",\"IP\":\"10.0.0.0:901\",\"Currency\":\"EUR\"}]}}"

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with adding extra quotes missing parts as below

```
{"Init":{"MOP":[{"Id":"1","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXB","TerminalId":"'P400Plus-275008565'","IP":"'192.168.1.15'","Currency":"EUR"},{"Id":"2","Type":"0","ProtocolVersion":"1.0","MopCode":"*NEXF","TerminalId":"'P400Plus-275008565'","IP":"'10.0.0.0:901'","Currency":"EUR"}]}}
```